# Differentiability for $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=Ax\cdot x=x^\top \cdot Ax$ where $A\in M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Q: Show that $f$ is differentiable and the total derivative $Df(a)(h)=Aa\cdot h+Ah\cdot a$.
$$\\$$ My attempt: Firstly, I calculate $$f(a+h)-f(a)-Aa\cdot h-Ah\cdot a\\=a^\top Aa+a^\top Ah+h^\top Aa+h^\top Ah-a^\top Aa-h^\top Aa-a^\top Ah\\=h^\top Ah $$
Consider $$\lvert \frac{h^\top Ah}{\lVert h \rVert}\rvert=\lvert\frac{(h_1,\cdots,h_n)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{j=1}^n A_{1j}h_j \\ \vdots\\ \sum_{j=1}^n A_{nj}h_j\end{pmatrix}}{\lVert h\rVert}\rvert =\lvert \frac {h_1\sum_{j=1}^n A_{1j}h_j+\cdots+h_n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{nj}h_j}{\lVert h \rVert}\rvert\\\leqslant \frac{\lvert h_1 \rvert\lVert A_1 \rVert\lVert h \rVert+\cdots+\lvert h_n \rvert\lVert A_n \rVert\lVert h \rVert}{\lVert h \rVert}$$ 
by C-S inequality and $A_i$ is $i_{th}$ row of $A$, so
$$=\lvert h_1 \rvert \lVert A_1 \rVert+\cdots+\lvert h_n\rvert\lVert A_n \rVert\to 0   $$ as $h\to 0$.

I'm wondering other more intuitive ways to think of this problem, especially I am confused the derivative of a function with matrix.

Comment: You can do partial derivatives by components and show they are continuous.

Comment: @Miguel I don't know how to calculate partial derivative with matrix.

Comment: Try writing $f$ explicitly including the components of the matrix $A$. Also I think you mean $f(x)$, not $f(A)$, which changes everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$ f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R \hskip10ex f(x):= Ax\cdot x \hskip5ex [A\in \text{Mat}(m;\mathbb R)] $$

[Incidentally, the title says $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, but the result is valid in the general case.]

If $\;a\in\mathbb R^m\;$ is fixed, we have, for each $h\in\mathbb R^m$:

\begin{align}
f(a+h)-f(a) &= A(a+h)\cdot(a+h)-Aa\cdot a = \\
            &= (Aa+Ah)\cdot(a+h)-Aa\cdot a = \\
            &= Aa\cdot a + Aa\cdot h + Ah\cdot a + Ah\cdot h -Aa\cdot a= \\
            &= Aa\cdot h + Ah\cdot a + Ah\cdot h
\end{align}

and then it is sufficient to note that

- $ h \mapsto Aa\cdot h + Ah\cdot a\;\;$ is linear $\;\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$
- $\displaystyle\frac{|Ah\cdot h|}{\|h\|} \leq \frac{\|Ah\|\cdot\|h\|}{\|h\|} = \|Ah\| \leq \|A\|\cdot\|h\|\to 0\;\;$ as $\;h\to0$

to conclude that

$$ Df(a)\;:\;h \mapsto Df(a)(h)=Aa\cdot h + Ah\cdot a. $$

Comment: I think  $\lVert Ah \cdot h \rVert$ is $\lvert Ah \cdot h \rvert$ and use Cauchy Schwarz inequality to get $\lvert Ah \cdot h \rvert \leqslant  \lVert Ah \rVert \cdot \lVert h \rVert$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited, thanks!